# Can I use MKL libraries provided by Anaconda with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, anaconda, intel-mkl, netlib

I want to use MKL libraries provided with Anaconda with Spark. I installed libgfortran

```
conda install libgfortran
```

linked libs

```
ln -s $PATH_TO_ANACONDA/lib/libmkl_rt.so  $PATH_TO_ANACONDA/lib/liblapack.so.3
ln -s  $PATH_TO_ANACONDA/lib/libmkl_rt.so $ PATH_TO_ANACONDA/lib/libblas.so.3
```

and placed  PATH_TO_ANACONDA/lib on LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH_TO_ANACONDA/lib
```

but when I run Spark [ALS example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#examples) I see

```
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
```

so i think it didn't work. Is something clearly wrong with this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use any library as long as you load it to the nodes. Use --packages with the libraries you would like to use